# Jackson XmlMapper generates wrong XML entries order

Tags: java, xml, jackson

I have an issue with generating a XML string with the Java Jackson XmlMapper: It generates the wrong order of entries in the XML string, nevertheless I use @JsonPropertyOrder and the members are in the needed order inside the class.
Please see my code:

```
@JsonPropertyOrder({ "craneNumber", "moveType", "reference", "unitNumber", "ISOCode", "IMOLabels", "seal", "doorDirection" })
public class OcrDataResultUnit {
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName="unit")
    private String craneNumber;
    private String moveType;
    private String reference;
    private String unitNumber;
    @JsonProperty("ISOCode")
    private String isoCode;
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName="IMOLabels")
    @JsonProperty("DGSIMOClass")
    private List<String> imoLabels = new ArrayList<>();
    @JsonProperty("seal")
    private String seal;
    @JsonProperty("doorDirection")
    private String doorDirection;

    // all getters and setters ...
```

Usage:

```
    XmlMapper mapper = new XmlMapper();
    String msgXml = mapper.writeValueAsString(this);
```

Result:

```
<unit>
<craneNumber>QC01</craneNumber>
<moveType>D</moveType>
<reference>12345678901234567890123456789012</reference>
<unitNumber>ABCD00001234</unitNumber>
<ISOCode>22G1</ISOCode>
<seal>Y</seal>
<doorDirection>H</doorDirection>
<IMOLabels>
<DGSIMOClass>1.5</DGSIMOClass>
<DGSIMOClass>2.1</DGSIMOClass>
</IMOLabels>
</unit>
```

- I get the same result without the @JsonProperty on the last to members. That was a try.
- The structure is part of a bigger XML structure.
- Also replaced @JsonProperty with @JacksonXmlProperty: Same result.
- As far as I see @JsonPropertyOrder is correct to be used for XML as well.

Does anybody have an idea?
Maybe I am just blind - actually I hope so :-)

Thank you and best regards

Comment: DGSIMOClass should probably be used instead of IMOLabels in the JsonPropertyOrder tag, given it's your property name. Can you check if this solves your problem?

Comment: Right! That was it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome! I've added an answer to the question. Please accept it :)

Comment: Done. I just cannot vote it up. I have too less reputation points yet :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your JsonPropertyOrder annotation, the property is called "DGSIMOClass", not "IMOLabels". You should switch it out for the correct name.